# Why does `xs reverse_::: ys` work?

Tags: scala

From the API documentation for `List`:

> Adds the elements of a given list in reverse order in front of this list. `xs reverse_::: ys` is equivalent to `xs.reverse ::: ys` but is more efficient.

What confuses me is why `xs.reverse ::: ys` works, i.e. replacing the underscore with a blank.

Is this a type of expansion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do `xs reverse_::: ys`, you are just calling a function called `reverse_:::`.

When you do `xs.reverse ::: ys`, you first call the `reverse` function on `xs`, then you call the `:::` function.

`xs.reverse ::: ys` will iterate through the elements in `xs` twice. First when you reverse `xs`, then a second time when you append the result of `reverse` to `ys`. The `reverse_:::` function will do both operations with a single iteration over `xs`.

Comment: None of `reverse_:::`, `reverse`, and `:::` are functions. They are methods.